# Javascript files clashing, please suggest changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a view page out of html code and source files of 2 bootstrap templates. Both templates are using different java script files to different features. As i am using both js files in 1 html view page, features of one js file is not working.

Two js files i am using are: `jquery-2.1.1.min.js` and `jQuery-2.1.4.min.js`

Please suggest some alternative or any way out to combine both these files in single so that all features are working.

```js
    <!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
    <script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.2 -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
    <script>
      $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
    </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.2 JS -->

    <!-- Morris.js charts -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/morris/morris.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Sparkline -->
    <script src="plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
    <script src="plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- daterangepicker -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- datepicker -->
    <script src="plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Slimscroll -->
    <script src="plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src='plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js'></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="dist/js/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    
    <!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
    <script src="dist/js/pages/dashboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    
    <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
    






  <!-- start: MAIN JAVASCRIPTS -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="assets/plugins/respond.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/excanvas.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
  <script src="assets/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/blockUI/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/iCheck/jquery.icheck.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/src/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/src/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootbox/bootbox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/jquery.scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/ScrollToFixed/jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/jquery.appear/jquery.appear.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/velocity/jquery.velocity.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/TouchSwipe/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
  <!-- end: MAIN JAVASCRIPTS -->
  <!-- start: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR SUBVIEW CONTENTS -->
  <script src="assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-mockjax/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/toastr/toastr.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-switch/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-fileupload/bootstrap-fileupload.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="assets/plugins/truncate/jquery.truncate.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/summernote/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/subview.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/subview-examples.js"></script>
  <!-- end: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR SUBVIEW CONTENTS -->
  <!-- start: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/nvd3/lib/d3.v3.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/nvd3/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/nvd3/src/models/historicalBar.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/nvd3/src/models/historicalBarChart.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/nvd3/src/models/stackedArea.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/nvd3/src/models/stackedAreaChart.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/jquery.sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/easy-pie-chart/dist/jquery.easypiechart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/index.js"></script>
  <!-- end: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
  <!-- start: CORE JAVASCRIPTS  -->
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
  <!-- end: CORE JAVASCRIPTS  -->
  <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    Main.init();
    SVExamples.init();
    Index.init();
   });
  </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AdminLTE 2 | Dashboard</title>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.4 -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
    <!-- FontAwesome 4.3.0 -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Ionicons 2.0.0 -->
    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins 
         folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <link href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link href="plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Morris chart -->
    <link href="plugins/morris/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <link href="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Date Picker -->
    <link href="plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Daterange picker -->
    <link href="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
    <link href="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->




  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,500,600,700,200,100,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/iCheck/skins/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/src/perfect-scrollbar.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/animate.css/animate.min.css">
  <!-- end: MAIN CSS -->
  <!-- start: CSS REQUIRED FOR SUBVIEW CONTENTS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl-carousel/owl.transitions.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/summernote/dist/summernote.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/bootstrap-switch/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/DataTables/media/css/DT_bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/bootstrap-fileupload/bootstrap-fileupload.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css">
  <!-- end: CSS REQUIRED FOR THIS SUBVIEW CONTENTS-->
  <!-- start: CSS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/weather-icons/css/weather-icons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/nvd3/nv.d3.min.css">
  <!-- end: CSS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
  <!-- start: CORE CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles-responsive.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/plugins.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/themes/theme-style8.css" type="text/css" id="skin_color">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print"/>
  <!-- end: CORE CSS -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />








  </head>
  <body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">
      
      content
      
      </div>
    

    <!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
    <script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.2 -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
    <script>
      $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
    </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.2 JS -->

    <!-- Morris.js charts -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/morris/morris.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Sparkline -->
    <script src="plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
    <script src="plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- daterangepicker -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- datepicker -->
    <script src="plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Slimscroll -->
    <script src="plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src='plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js'></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="dist/js/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    
    <!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
    <script src="dist/js/pages/dashboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    
    <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
    






  <!-- start: MAIN JAVASCRIPTS -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="assets/plugins/respond.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/excanvas.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
  <script src="assets/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/blockUI/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/iCheck/jquery.icheck.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/src/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/src/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootbox/bootbox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/jquery.scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/ScrollToFixed/jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/jquery.appear/jquery.appear.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/velocity/jquery.velocity.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/TouchSwipe/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
  <!-- end: MAIN JAVASCRIPTS -->
  <!-- start: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR SUBVIEW CONTENTS -->
  <script src="assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-mockjax/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/toastr/toastr.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-switch/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-fileupload/bootstrap-fileupload.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="assets/plugins/truncate/jquery.truncate.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/summernote/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/subview.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/subview-examples.js"></script>
  <!-- end: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR SUBVIEW CONTENTS -->
  <!-- start: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/nvd3/lib/d3.v3.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/nvd3/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/nvd3/src/models/historicalBar.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/nvd3/src/models/historicalBarChart.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/nvd3/src/models/stackedArea.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/nvd3/src/models/stackedAreaChart.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/jquery.sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/easy-pie-chart/dist/jquery.easypiechart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/index.js"></script>
  <!-- end: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
  <!-- start: CORE JAVASCRIPTS  -->
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
  <!-- end: CORE JAVASCRIPTS  -->
  <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    Main.init();
    SVExamples.init();
    Index.init();
   });
  </script>
 </body>
 <!-- end: BODY -->
 </html>
```

Comment: Load `jQuery` and `jQuery-ui` only once on the page

Comment: Have you tried only loading one of the jQuery files? There's a good chance you'll be fine if you only load 2.1.4.

Comment: yes i tried loading one of these files but that is giving featues of one template only.

Comment: @tushar , can you suggest how can i combine both these js files into single so that i will be able use once on page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only jQuery-2.1.4.min.js and in addition to this you may need to use [Jquery.migrate.js](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/).

Basically, This plugin can be used to detect and restore APIs or features that have been deprecated in jQuery previous versions than this. So you will be able to access both the jquery file methods.

Your code will look like this then:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hope you have used the version instead of {latestversion} in migrate.js ?

Comment: i used what you wrote above.

Comment: i used :<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script> Still it is not working

Comment: thanks ....... i changed positions of source files, now everything is working fine.

Comment: @akhilverma welcome, You mean you called migrate.js first and then jquery file? or you called both jquery files ?

Comment: i included both js files ...... in addition i had to change some position of other souce files ....... src files of one template initially placed in botton, i placed them above src files of other template.

Comment: dont know what change it made after just changing position of files but then it worked fine.